# Finding a function with a functional equation.

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

A function $f:\mathbb{R^{+}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}}$ which satisfies the functional equation $$f((c+1)x+f(y))=2cx+f(x+2y)$$
Where $c$ is a positive constant, Find all such possible functions.

I tried putting $y=1$ but $f((c+1)x+f(1))$ made things tougher. I am unable to solve this could someone help me?

Comment: Try with a fixed $c$, like $ c=1$, and see what you get. Even the edge case of $ c = 0 $ might be instructive.

Comment: @Chesx FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f((c%2B1)x%2Bf(y))%3D2cx%2Bf(x%2B2y)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive&p=1), there's the related AoPS thread [Algebra problem 189](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1611727p10066028).

Comment: Start by setting $x=0$ and using various values of $y$. It should give you some ideas.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You technically can't use $x = 0$ since $f$ is only defined on the positive real numbers. However, trying out a variety of values of $x$ and $y$ is definitely the start point.

Comment: @ConMan Actually, one *can* use $x = 0$ since the problem doesn't specifically restrict what values are allowed for $x$ and $y$ so, as long as $y \gt 0$, then the arguments for *all* of the $f()$ functions used in the expression would be positive.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that's a nice hint I never thought x could be $0$. And secondly I didn't believe the solution on AOPS is correct.

Comment: John, It could depend on how well OP @Chesx transcribed the problem. EG In the AOPS link, there is the restriction that $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$.   $\quad$ At the end of the day, we do not need to use $ x = 0 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the idea of substituion, which consists in equating subfunctional expressions. And this is the case where this idea helps to see the implicit constraints imposed on the function by the original functional equation: $$(c+1)x+f(y)=x+2y\Rightarrow cx+f(y)=2y\Rightarrow f(y)\ge 2y, \; y\in \mathbb R^+\qquad(1)$$ In deed, if the inequality higher isn't satisfied for some $y_0$, then exists $x_0$ such that equality $(c+1)x_0+f(y_0)=x_0+2y_0$ is reached and it leads to $$f((c+1)x_0+f(y_0))=2cx_0+f(x_0+2y_0)\Rightarrow0=2cx_0$$ what is impossible.
Now one of the natural ideas is to find an upper limiting expression. Let's use $(1)$: $$f((c+1)x+f(y))\ge 2(c+1)x+2f(y)\Rightarrow$$ $$ \Rightarrow 2cx+f(x+2y)\ge 2(c+1)x+2f(y)\Rightarrow $$ $$\Rightarrow f(x+2y)\ge 2x+2f(y) \qquad (2) $$ $$ f((c+1)x+2\frac{f(y)}{2})\ge 2(c+1)x+2f(\frac{f(y)}{2})\Rightarrow $$ $$\Rightarrow 2cx+f(x+2y)\ge 2(c+1)x+2f(\frac{f(y)}{2})\Rightarrow $$ $$\Rightarrow f(x+2y)\ge 2x+2f(\frac{f(y)}{2})\Rightarrow f(y)\le 4y, \; y\in \mathbb R^+ \qquad (3)$$
Let's suppose exists $y_1$ such that $(3)$ isn't satisfied. Then it's obvious exists $x_1$ such that: $$2x_1+4y_1=f(y_1)\Rightarrow x_1+2y_1=\frac{f(y_1)}{2}\Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow f(x_1+2y_1)\ge 2x_1+2f(\frac{f(y_1)}{2})\Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow 0 \ge 2x_1+f(\frac{f(y_1)}{2})$$ what is impossible.
Now let's suppose exists $y_3$ such that $f(y_3)\gt 2y_3 \; (4)$. Then exists $a \in (2;4]$ such that $f(x)\le ax, \; x \in \mathbb R^+$ and for any sufficiently small $\varepsilon \gt 0$ we can choose $x_3$ such that $f(x_3)\ge (a-\varepsilon)x_3$. The idea here is to use the existence of such "critical" points of function to find even stronger restrictions on the function. Let's promote this idea:
$$(c+1)x+f(y)=x_3 \Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow f((c+1)x+f(y))=(a-\varepsilon)(c+1)x+(a-\varepsilon)f(y)=2cx+f(x+2y) \le 2cx+ax+2ay \Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow (a-\varepsilon)(c+1)x+(a-\varepsilon)f(y) \le 2cx+ax+2ay \Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow (a-\varepsilon)(c+1)x+2(a-\varepsilon)y \le 2cx+ax+2ay \Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow ((a-2-\varepsilon)c-\varepsilon)x \le 2\varepsilon y \qquad (5)$$
Note that in the $(5)$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ expression $((a-2-\varepsilon)c-\varepsilon)x$ is positive (since $a,c$ are fixed numbers in this context). As $y\to0$ we get $2\varepsilon y\to0$ while $x\to \frac{x_3}{c+1}$ and $((a-2-\varepsilon)c-\varepsilon)x \to ((a-2-\varepsilon)c-\varepsilon)\frac{x_3}{c+1}$, so the (5) isn't satisfied (since $(3)$ we get $f(y)\to 0$ as $y\to0$, it also explains, why substitution $(c+1)x+f(y)=x_3$ is legal).
From above we get assumption $(4)$ is false and assuming $(1)$ we conclude $$f(x) \equiv 2x$$ is the only solution of the original functional equation.